# Find a video and sounds

Tags: video, webvideos

I am looking for a video which start at the top of ocean surface for few seconds and then beginning to go under the surface. There should be no people on the video. But fish and other sea creatures can be there.

Also I am looking for interesting sounds which I can add to the video like dolphin sounds, whale sounds and specially a Submarine like sound which gives the user a good feeling that they are going underwater little by little.

It would also help if I can find a place where I can get few lines of text spoken out in a nice voice which would match the video

Comment: Yeah, I tried some sites like videohive

Comment: For the [voice over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-over), try [Voice123](http://voice123.com/) or [Voice Bunny](https://voicebunny.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [videoblocks](https://www.videoblocks.com/). They are a subscription based stock footage site.
Here is [a clip](https://www.videoblocks.com/video/water-surface-and-tadpoles-zninzrg/) I found that is similar to what you are looking for.
Consider using my [referal link](http://videoblocks.refr.cc/ZLK8VQG) to sign up for videoblocks.

---

For sound effects, check out [audioblocks](https://www.audioblocks.com/) (a sister sight to videoblocks).
They have sound effects for dolphins, whales, and lots of different water sounds.
Consider using my [referral link](http://audioblocks.refr.cc/KD9KXBT) to sign up for audioblocks.

P.S. I am not affiliated with videoblocks or audioblocks in any way.